# Delete all those columns from matrix which contains all values are '0' in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a large matrix data which are based on row and columns, I want to delete all those columns which contain all values are `0` in MATLAB.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `all` with a second input to check which columns have all zeros. This will return a `logical` array that is `true` when all rows of a given column satisfy a condition and `false` otherwise. You can then use the inverse of the result as a logical index to select only the columns that don't satisfy this criteria

```
data = data(:, ~all(data == 0, 1));
```

Alternately, you could use `any` in a similar way. `any` will return a logical array that is `true` when there is any row in a column that satisfies the condition and `false` otherwise.

```
data = data(:, any(data ~= 0, 1));
```

This one can be simplified even further though since internally, `any` will cast `data` as a `logical` value turning any non-zero value into `true` and any zero value into `false.

```
data = data(:, any(data, 1));
```

If you are working with floating point numbers, you'll want to use a very small epsilon rather than comparing numbers *directly* to 0

```
data = data(:, ~all(abs(data) < eps, 1));
data = data(:, any(abs(data) > eps, 1));
```

Comment: @user3638860 If this worked for you consider marking it as a solution